# Error insertion PHP

Tags: php, mysql, oop, insert

I am starting to study OO php and I have a certain problems.

In this code below I am trying to do a single insertion in the bank. It's very simple, but I'm already having problems.

When I try to send the following error appears:

`Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\test\web\testoo\Aluno.Controle.php on line 24`

Aluno.class.php

```
<?php
Class Aluno{

private $cpf;

    public function setCPF($cpf)
    {
        $this->cpf = $cpf;
    }

    public function getCPF()
    {
        return $this->cpf;
    }
}
?>
```

Aluno.Controle.php

```
<?php
include ('Aluno.class.php');
include ('Banco.php');

$cpf=$_POST['cpf'];

Class AlunoControle {

    private $consulta;

    public function AlunoDao() {

        $novaconexao = new Banco();
        $this->consulta = $novaconexao->conectar(); 

    }

    public function CadastrarAluno($cpf) {

        $this->AlunoDao();
        $cadastrar = new Aluno;
        $cadastrar->setCPF($cpf);

        $query = ("INSERT into cadastro values (". $aluno->getCPF() .")");
        $this->consulta->query($query);


    }
}

$pessoa2 = new AlunoControle();
$pessoa2->CadastrarAluno($cpf);
```

Banco.php

```
<?php

Class Banco{

    private $host  = "localhost"; 
    private $user  = "root"; 
    private $pass  = "";
    private $banco = "testephp";
    private $MySQLi;


    public function conectar(){
        $MySQLi = new mysqli( $this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->banco );

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die(mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }
            echo "Conectado com sucesso!!!";
    }

    public function desconectar() {
        if ($this->MySQLi) {
            mysqli_close ($this->MySQLi); 
        } 
        //echo "Desconectado com sucesso!!!";
    }
}
```

index.html

```
<form id="frm-cadastro" class="frm" method="post" action="Aluno.Controle.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend align="center">Cadastro de Notícias</legend>

                    <label for="noticia">
                        Notícia:
                    CPF: <input name="cpf" type="text"><br>

                    </label>

                    <div id="botoes">
                        <input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar" />

                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: Do you have a method 'query' in the object 'Banco' ? Ok, don't see the wrong constructor...

Comment: That means `$this->consulta` is not a valid database connection object. Debug why.

Comment: OT: you have an unescaped variable in you code (`$cpf=$_POST['cpf']`), it will lead to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

Your not set the value to `private property $consulta` before call `CadastrarAluno`.

Try this code:

```
Class AlunoControle {

    private $consulta;

    public function __construct() {

        $novaconexao = new Banco();
            $this->consulta = $novaconexao->conectar();

    }

    public function CadastrarAluno($cpf) {

        $this->AlunoDao();
        $cadastrar = new Aluno;
        $cadastrar->setCPF($cpf);

        if ($this->consulta->query("INSERT into cadastro values (".$aluno->getCPF().")")) {
        }
    }
}
```

In this code, your set value to property `consulta` in class constructor.

Comment: Hello, sorry for wait. Im try but keep error now in:  

*Fatal error: Call to undefined method AlunoControle::AlunoDao() in C:\test\web\testeoo\Aluno.Controle.php on line 20*

Answer (score 1):

This should be

```
public function __construct() {

        $novaconexao = new Banco();
            $this->consulta = $novaconexao->conectar();

    }
```

`$this->consulta` will be initalize when object is created

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the error message, the `$this->consulta` property is not set as an object.

This means that something is going wrong when you do:

```
$novaconexao = new Banco();
$this->consulta = $novaconexao->conectar();
```

So either the `conectar()` method is not returning an object or, most likely, for some reason the connection to the database fails.

Comment: I make this difference:

$query = ("INSERT into cadastro values (". $aluno->getCPF() .")");
$this->consulta->query($query);

Now error appears:
Notice: Undefined variable: aluno in C:\test\web\testeoo\Aluno.Controle.php on line 24

Fatal error: Call to a member function getCPF() on a non-object in C:\test\web\testeoo\Aluno.Controle.php on line 24

Comment: About the first error you posted, add: return $MySQLi;
This way it returns the object you need to call the query() method.

About the second error, replace $aluno with $cadastrar